# Unable to cast element in ForEach Loop to NSManagedObject Subclass SwiftUI

Tags: objective-c, swift, swiftui, nsmanagedobject, swift5

I got a ListView in **SwiftUI** and want to generate RowViews depending on a given property.
Therefore I want to check the property of the element in the **ForEach** loop.

Xcode does not recognize the type of the element, thats why i want to cast the element to the correct Class which is an **NSManagedObject Subclass**.

I created the NSManagedObject Subclass from the xcdatamodeld (Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass...).

The NSManagedObject Subclass is created in objective-c and I added the .h file to the bridging header.

I have no problem working with the NSManagedObject Subclass in the rest of the project. 
I can even create an property of that Type in the same Struct like so:

```
struct MyListView: View {

    var test : MyNSManagedObjectSubclass //Xcode does recognize it here
```

For some reason **Xcode wont recognize the NSManagedObject Subclass inside the ForEach Loop.**

code looks like:

```
struct MyListView: View {

    var test : MyNSManagedObjectSubclass //Xcode does recognize it here
    @EnvironmentObject private var fetchResultsContainer : FetchedResultsContainer

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                ForEach(fetchResultsContainer.results , id: \.identifier) { result in
                    if let castedResult = result as! MyNSManagedObjectSubclass { //Xcode does not recognize it here
                        if castedResult.property{
                            ResultRowView(input: result)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FetchedResultsContainer:

```
@objc class FetchedResultsContainer : NSObject, ObservableObject{

    @objc @Published var results: [MyNSManagedObjectSubclass]()

    @objc static let sharedInstance: FetchedResultsContainer = {
        let instance = FetchedResultsContainer()

        return instance
    }()
}
```

I feel like im missing something obvious, as im still quite new to Swift and SwiftUI.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: How do you declare `results`?

Comment: So why do you check it? It declared as `results: [MyNSManagedObjectSubclass]`, so results will always contains MyNSManagedObjectSubclass objects.

Comment: i think the origin of my problem is, that i get `let result: <<error type>>`, by alt clicking `result`. 
And therefore im not able to check `result.property == true` because `result` is not recognized to be of type MyNSManagedObjectSubclass. i thought i could fix that by casting it to MyNSManagedObjectSubclass again.

Comment: sorry for my wrong terms when i said casting i actually mean: checking it with `if result is MyNSManagedObjectSubclass` 
you are correct, i can delete the check, but my problem still is, that i can not get `result.property`

Comment: thank you for helping me clarify my question. I adjusted the sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after taking a step back and simply coding it again from scratch it simply worked an no casting was needed...

```
List(fetchResultsContainer.results, id: \.identifier) { result in
    if (result.property == 0) {
    //do something
    }
}
```

My assumption that the casting was not working was not correct.
I probably checked `result.property == false`, with `property` being of type `NSNumber` and it gave out some strange compile errors that led me on the wrong path.